# How to add Model project XML comments in Swagger doc file

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a solution with multiple projects in it. One is a Web API Core project and another is a model project. I have configured Swagger documentation for both of them. The problem I am having is that both projects got separate XML files. How can I have it in a single file? Below is the code from my Program.cs file:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: you can't because they are generated on building two separate projects. but what is the real problem here. what is the problem of having two files. with swagger you get only one file at the end. so it does not matter if there are two files or three files.

Comment: @CodingMytra where will I get one file only. JSON file is containing all the details. But what about XML. We generally shares XML file to client applications?

Comment: which client application ? you question says swagger so i don't see any problem in generating multiple xml files as long as everything happening automatically and no manual intervention

Comment: @CodingMytra I meant to say, We share XML file to any application which would supposed to consume APIs. Those applications will refer XML to understand API details. That XML file is generated by Swagger, right?

Comment: but your question is saying swagger doesn't it ? and swagger will generate only one json file which you will share with other clients. if you are sharing the xml file then you have to write the merging logic of two xml file. it is nothing to do with swagger as swagger does not generate this xml files.

Comment: XML files are not generated by Swagger or swashbuckle. they are being generated during build.

Comment: @CodingMytra ohok. I was under impression that we generally shares XML file not JSON. Any pointer to merge those 2 files in case if I need to merge it. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's the good idea of merging these files. json file should be sufficient to provide API information.

Comment: @CodingMytra. Ok. I got you. But I am new to Swagger thing. So if I want to share it, where will it be placed when I deploy the application to dev/prod. How to share it.

Comment: normally swagger json gets generated during runtime (there is a way to generate during build also using swagger cli) and will get served when you call swagger endpoint, there is no need to separately deploy or share with anyone.

Comment: Ok ok. Thanks for all information and help.